# sed substitute each character until a pattern occurs

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have an pattern which consists of digits and commas, like this: `123,45,2,14324`. There can be any number of digits, and I have no way of knowing how many digits there is between two commas. I need to replace each digit with letter 'k', so `129,54,0,111` becomes `kkk,kk,k,kkk`. I need to replace it only if a certain pattern occurs before it, and it always appears on a line like this:
`mypattern:123,421,9,3  pattern_i_don't_need:1499,242,22,1`

I need to substitute each digit which directly follows `mypattern:`, so the example line needs to be changed to:

`mypattern:kkk,kkk,k,k  pattern_i_don't_need:1499,242,22,1`

I can use only sed and/or grep. 
So far I've learned how to substitute each character on the line in question, like this:

```
   sed '/^mypattern:/ s/[0-9]/k/g'
```

This version finds a line which starts with `mypattern:` and substitutes each digit on that line. How can I tell sed to 'stop' and not substitute whatever digits occur after spaces and/or letters?

Comment: `mypattern:kkk,kkk,k,k  pattern_i_don't_need:1499,242,22,1` will always be in same line? or can it be in different lines?

Comment: Yes, it will always be in the same line; it's always `mypattern` at the beginning without any preceding characters, then digits I need to replace with 'k's, then some amount of spaces and letters (the amount of those is not fixed, could be different on each line), then some more digits with commas that do not need to be changed; and that's a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a sed command like this:

```
sed -r ':a s/(mypattern:[k,]*)[0-9]/\1k/; t a' yourfile
```

- `:a` is a label that `t a` jumps to in case `s` has done a substitution
- thus you have a "loop":

  ```
  while s has replaced one digit with a "k":
      try again to: 
          replace another digit after 
               "mypattern:" and an optional sequence of "k" and comma:
          with k
  ```

Comment: Note that you can remove the test `/mypattern:/`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You are right, the mypattern in the `s` is sufficient. I simplified the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk to:

```
awk '/^mypattern/ && gsub(/[0-9]/,"k",$1)' file
```

Same concept just awk gives you the option of working on the first column of data separated by white space.